# Close open dialogs / bottom sheets upon navigation from NavigationBar

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

How can I close any open dialogs/bottom-sheets when the user clicks on the [NavigationBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/NavigationBar-class.html) items? It essentially Navigates away, but from a `NavigationBar` that is higher up in the widget tree than the widget that opened the dialog/bottom-sheet, so the dialog/bottom-sheet just stays open.

Here is the NavigationBar (I'm using [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) to navigate):

```
WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: () {
              return Future.value(false);
            },
            child: Scaffold(bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(
            height: BOTTOM_NAV_HEIGHT,
            selectedIndex: currentIndex(widget._routerState.location),
            onDestinationSelected: (index) => onItemTapped(context, index),
            destinations: primaryDestinations,
          ),....),)

  int currentIndex(String location) => _locationToTabIndex(location);

  void onItemTapped(BuildContext context, int tabIndex) {
    if (tabIndex != currentIndex(GoRouter.of(context).location)) {
      context.go(primaryDestinations[tabIndex].route);
    }
  }

  int _locationToTabIndex(String location) {
    final index =
        primaryDestinations.indexWhere((t) => location.startsWith(t.route));
    return index < 0 ? 0 : index;
  }
```